# Failed to execute aapt

Tags: build.gradle

Please help solving this error:

```
Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor540.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
```

Comment: Try running gradle build with --info parameter. You might find what's the problem, in my case it was using `aaptOptions { additionalParameters '--utf16' }`

Comment: thanks @nicolas Azrak. but i found another solution.

Comment: in my case when i was upgrade gradle to 4.1 then it was happened.my sugesstion is that don't upgrade gradle to 4.1 in android studio 3.0

Comment: This helped me find the problem ```gradlew.bat --info clean build ```

Comment: may you can Downgrade from gradle-4.4-all to gradle-4.1-all in file gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: what is the solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Add the plugin "cordova-android-support-gradle-release" in package.json.
It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Well, what if you have already been using that plugin for a while now and this error just started happening? I'm not finding anything helpful, anywhere.

Comment: @TheTC remove that plugin using some command and then install it appropriate version. If you are using ionic then use following command ionic cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release@latest

Answer (score 3):

For me, the case was bit different. I could build and debug unsigned APKs. Each time I tried to make a signed release with Jar signing, got this error. Restarting android studio didn't solve it.

This is how I solved it.

It happened that my complete address of the project had white spaces. D:\Google Drive\blah blah . . . .Changed it to GoogleDrive, reloaded the project and the issue was gone.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

To your gradle.properties file

[image]

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
android.enableAapt2=false
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=xxxxxxx
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=xxxxx
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error, but `cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release` worked for me. Worth to give it a try if it is not installed.