# Failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources' Failed to execute aapt

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Questions what I tried:

[Gradle Build Failed For Task app:processReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407479/gradle-build-failed-for-task-appprocessreleaseresources)
[Failed to execute aapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993773/failed-to-execute-aapt)

---

What I did:
I followed the React Native [Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)

But at the part of `$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease` and I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

[Full build log](http://rwalstijn.mtdef.com/logs/react-native/openapp/fullBuild.log)

This is not solved with this question: "[Gradle Build Failed For Task app:processReleaseResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407479/gradle-build-failed-for-task-appprocessreleaseresources)" for me.

This are the build tools versions is tried: (in the file: `build.gradle`)

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" // Android SDK Build-Tools
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2" // Android SDK Build-Tools
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2" // Android SDK Build-Tools
buildToolsVersion "26.1.1" // Android Tools
buildToolsVersion "27.0.1" // Android SDK Platform-Tools
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" // Android SDK Build-Tools
```

I have all the build tools versions installed from the `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK` page tab SDK Tools

The `buildToolsVersion "26.1.1" // Android Tools` Is the only one thats not giving me this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

But the error is:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 26.1.1
```

Therefore I found: [Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683726/failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-1)
But that answer did not work.

> ```
> $ android list sdk -a
> ```

Did not work and returned `bash: android: command not found`

**PS I am a newbie at react-native**

Comment: run packager, open android studio and open your react native project android folder in it and check logcat after opening the app.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza thanks for the comment. I can not find logcat in my Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html) or the logcat command-line (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html)

Comment: [logcat in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857560/how-to-find-error-from-logcat-in-android/25279937) it is used to see any info, warnings or errors while debugging the android app.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza Sorry for asking but how will logcat help me with building a signed APK?? The `react-native run-android` is working fine...

Comment: I am not giving you the signed apk building command, I am giving you the way to check what error stopping the build process to find the exact issue.

Comment: @ShahzadMirza Sorry It was not clear for me that the issue could be in the app. I thought that the problem was in the setup of Android Studio or in the `build.gradle`

Comment: whatever the issue is it will give you proper error information.

Comment: Can you add the full build log? It should contain the error from AAPT.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I added a link to the full build log

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in the build log is:

> C:\Users\gebr\Documents\Flavour\openapp\svs_app\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.

It means that most likely you're using a plugin that tries to add files to the release merged resources folder. In Android Gradle Plugin AAPT2 is enabled by default and therefore the files in the merged folder are compiled by it (.flat files).
The owners of the plugin should update their code to first compile the resources using AAPT2 before putting them into the merged folder, or even better, pass them as a source-set input to the merge resources task (not compiled). I'd strongly suggest the second approach.
Until the owners of the plugin do that, you might use an older version of the gradle plugin (before 3.0) or use the most recent one with the flag android.enableAapt2=false.

Comment: Just a note: yes, AAPT1 will be fully deprecated at some point in the future and so using the android.enableAapt2=false flag won't last forever. Please contact the owner of the misbehaving library/plugin so they are aware of the issue and can fix it in time.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android.enableAapt2=false`

in android/gradle.properties

Comment: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated now